# How to compare two tables each having 500 columns using PL-SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I need to compare two tables in different databases and check whether the data in both tables are matching or not.

The compare should return a result showing rows that don't match using an exact column to column data check.

Is this possible in PL-SQL?

Comment: are the tow tables have the same fields and the same data type and the same name for each field ?? if yes, I have the answer

Comment: yes...same fields and data type but having 600 coulmns

Comment: and the tables are in different database also, i created database link to connect each othr

Answer (score 5):

To return all rows in table1 that do not match exactly the rows in table2:

```
select * from table1 except select * from table2
```

And to return all rows in table1 that match exactly what is in table2:

```
select * from table1 intersect select * from table2
```

Comment: +1 but you need to use MINUS not EXCEPT in Oracle for the first.

Comment: +1 I was trying to do it using dynamic sql your solution is much better